# Asp.net timer passed as ref to function in other form does not tick when enabled

Tags: c#, timer

In a C# asp.net project, when I pass a System.Web.UI.Timer object by reference to a routine in a different form and enable it within the routine, the Timer tick event on the calling does not execute.If the routine is in the same form, the Tick event executes when the timer is enabled

I have worked around this by not passing the Timer to the routine and enabling it in each form on the basis of the value returned by the routine.

Comment: What do you mean `pass to a different form`? A Web Application doesn't have persistent forms the way a desktop application has. There are only web requests. The server generates HTML in response to the requests and when it's done, it cleans up everything it created for that request. A `System.Web.UI.Timer` emits *Javascript* to the browser that causes a postback after every interval, it's not something that can be shared among pages

Comment: If you are starting with ASP.NET just now, I'd suggest you *don't* use WebForms at all. It will only confuse you. WebForms tried to make web development look like desktop development back when web pages were *very* simple. This doesn't work any more, which is why ASP.NET MVC was created

Comment: The [ASP.NET site](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/) contains a *lot* of tutorials and Getting Started guides

Comment: Thanks for your comments.  I have been able to pass label and textbox controls in this way and thought timers would be the same. The different form is in the Visual Studio 2013 C# source code. The advice to avoid WebForms is good in retrospect as the form design as shown in VS is very different from how it appears in a browser and tasks like showing a Wait cursor during long-running operations have proved impossible to implement. All my experience is with desktop apps which are very different.